Jbutton should open a JList and then append JtextArea but nothing happens when I press it?

 public static JButton scene() {
        JButton scene = new JButton("Scene");
        ImageIcon sceneIcon = new ImageIcon("src/Images/scene.png");
        scene.setIcon(sceneIcon);

        scene.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] entrances = {"EXT.", "INT."};
                JScrollPane header = new JScrollPane();
                JList<String> sceneTypeList = new JList<>(entrances);
                sceneTypeList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                sceneTypeList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
                sceneTypeList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
                sceneTypeList.setVisible(true);
                header.setSize(200, 200);
                header.add(sceneTypeList);
                Gui.textArea().add(header);


                if (sceneTypeList.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                    Gui.textDoc.append(entrances[0]);

                } else if (sceneTypeList.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                    Gui.textDoc.append(entrances[1]);
                }

            }
        });

public static final JTextArea textDoc = new JTextArea();
    protected static JFrame frame;

        private JFrame MyFrame() {
            frame = new JFrame();        //creates a frame
            frame.setTitle("Open Source ScriptWriter");  //sets title of frame
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //exit out of application
            frame.setResizable(true); //if set to false it'll make frame not resizable
            frame.setSize(940,820);     //sets dimensions and y-dimension of frame
            frame.setVisible(true);     //makes the frame visible
            frame.add(menuPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(marginPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
            frame.add(marginPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.add(counterPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.add(textArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("src/Images/camera.png");
            frame.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
            return frame;
        }

public static JPanel textArea(){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            panel.setBackground(Color.white);

            textDoc.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            textDoc.setMargin(new Insets(80,80,80,80));
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textDoc, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            panel.add(scrollPane);



            return panel;
        }


So basically when I click on that Scene button my hope is that a JList will pop up in the textArea Panel and ask if the user wants to create a EXT. or INT. scene and then paste in the textArea named textDoc. However when I click on the scene button it doesn't actually do anything. Normally I can write on the textDoc but when I click the scene button I'm not able to do that either. Is JList waiting for an action that it's not getting? Please advise.

Is JList waiting for an action that it's not getting? No. The code will be executed BEFORE the user has a chance to make a selection. Maybe use a JOptionPane prompt the user for input. The code after showing the option pane will not be executed until the user makes a selection and closes the dialog.

@camickr appreciate you brother. Added JOptionPane and now I'm getting the functionality that I needed.

Your program structure is off. When you call, Gui.textArea(), you create a JPanel, and then here, .add(header); you add a JScrollPane with components to it, but you do nothing with the JPanel created in the .textArea() method call. You do not add it to any top-level container, such as a JFrame or JPanel or any other component contained in such, and so the code in the end does nothing. Also, your methods posted above are all static methods, suggesting that your code may not be written to use Java's object oriented structure, increasing your code's risk for increased complexity and risk of bugs.
Better is to scrap all this code any ways and completely re-write your code so that good OOP code structure is used and so that components are created at program start up, and are all connected and ready to go. If you need to hide a component and then show it, then use a CardLayout.
